# The depth of pooling layer and prior convolution layer should same. But it is not same, kindly let me know the solutions

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, data-science, keras-layer

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=input_shape))

model.add(keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D(filters, filtersize, strides=(1, 1), padding='valid', data_format="channels_last", activation='relu'))

model.summary()
```

and output summary is :

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_10 (InputLayer)        (None, 300, 300, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_16 (Conv2D)           (None, 296, 296, 10)      760       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_13 (MaxPooling (None, 296, 148, 5)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
```

Above for conv2d_16  layer 10 is depth where as Maxpooling layer 5, how does it possible?

Comment: Is the code you posted complete? I don't see the pooling layer there. Even though, the answer is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very probably using the setting `data_format='channels_first'` in the pooling layer.

I see you added  `'channels_last'` to the convolutional layer, but you probably didn't add it to the pooling layer.

If you want to change the default setting for keras, find the `<user>/.keras/keras.json` file and change it there.

Comment: moller : its working.. thanks!!